# asp.net secure my application so no one can transfer it and reuse it

Tags: asp.net, database, security, iis

I'm making an asp.net web application which will run locally on IIS 
for a single user 
I don't want this user to access my application files (in the www root ) or bring another programmer and steal my code
I just want the user to have the ability to access the website only and 
stop any programmer from knowing my source code 
I heard about an USB security system called "Dongle" but can it be used in a situation like this ? 
any Ideas ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you compiling you ASP.NET site into a Web Application or are you leaving the code on the server and running it as a Web Site?  Do you have Admin privileges to the server where the site will run?  Does the client have Admin privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have *never* heard of a web application that uses a dongle.  This is normally reserved for regular windows apps; and even then it's falling out of vogue.  Generally speaking some of the more expensive software packages still use them.

However, the cost of duplicating a dongle is pretty low.  Combined with the fact that getting around such security is relatively easy anyway and you have a situation in which you really shouldn't bother.

As Simon said, if it's a web app host it.  Otherwise obfuscate it.

If neither of those are possible, then I'd recommend you change your licensing deal with your client to include the possibility of them going elsewhere.  Perhaps for an additional charge you'll give them a non-exclusive site license permitting them to do whatever they want with the code short of selling it or giving it to another entity.

Answer (score 2):

The website is just running code, but like anything, once the user has it they can do what they like to it, whether you  like it or not. That's why there is a multi-million {currency} industry around securing applications.

You could use dongles but they're expensive and not trivial to implement. As @volleyball said, obfuscation would slow down most people from decompiling your app. without odfucation any licensing or dongles could just be patched out of your code.

Your most secure route would be to not give it to them. It's a web app, host it. This may not of course not meet your requirements.

Simon

Comment: Absolutely agree here.  It's a web app, just host it.

Answer (score 1):

did you look at obfuscators. They do a good job at encrypting code. 99% of the time your code cannot be reverse engineered. But if someone sits on your stolen code they can reverse engineer.. In the sense that ordinary people may not obfuscate it. If the person is very intellingent, he will not reverse engineer he will write better code.